# Basic Matlab tables containing text

Tags: matlab

I need to type some matrix containing both letters and numbers.
Something like  list=["a" 1;" b" 2; "c" 3; "d" 4; "e" 5; "f" 6; "g" 7]

Can anybody give me some tip?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=matlab+array+with+strings+and+numbers

Comment: It is not clear whether "a" and 1 are part of the same element (you didn't separate them). I suspect you want either a cell array (allowing you to mix any data types) or a structure (allowing you to name data elements). But your question is really terribly unclear. Good questions get good answers.

Comment: cell arrays and tables ... that is what i need

Answer (score 1):

If you want "just" a mix of strings and numbers, use a cell array.  See the MATLAB documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html).

If you're trying to set up some kind of map/hash, you want a MATLAB "structure."  See the documentation for *that* [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html).

Comment: thank you both I am reading table and cell arrays documentation now